# Why is my State object being Changed? React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to merge two array objects by the `user_id` key. The two array objects I get are from the `state`.

```
function mapStateToProps(state) {

  let {users} = state.users.result;
  let {invite} = state.invite.result;
  let {friends} = state.friends.result;

  if (users && invite && friends) {

    let UsersList = mergeArray(users, invite.sent_invites); // Merge Users & Sent Invites
 }



function mergeArray(a, b) {
    return _.map(a, function(item) {
        return _.assign(item, _.find(b, ['user_id', item.user_id]));
      });

    }
```

However, my `{users}` state also changes with the merge. Why is this? I have been stuck on this hours.

Comment: users is a reference to state.users.result so your merge assign to this object. thats why your state object changes

Comment: How can I fix this?

Comment: Try {...users}.

Comment: `_.assign({}, item, _.find(b, ['user_id', item.user_id]));`

Comment: @dave, works! What happened?

Comment: `_.assign` assigns to the first argument, which in your cast was `item`, which was a reference to the object in `state.users`.  So you make your first argument an empty object, so you are writing to a new object each time and won't modify any existing ones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
_.assign({}, item, _.find(b, ['user_id', item.user_id]));
```

`_.assign` assigns to the first argument, which in your cast was `item`, which was a reference to the object in `state.users`.  So you make your first argument an empty object, so you are writing to a new object each time and won't modify any existing ones.